# When will median of two Databases sStop?

Tags: database, algorithm

I have a question about where to put my return statement in my pseudo-code.

The code is about finding the median of two data bases(each data base has n elements that are discrete) and uses a Divide and Conquer Formula. I need another condition to have my return statement about the result.
My first thought is to return when `median1 == median2' but I am not sure if it is right

```
median_of_datasets(p1,p2,start):
 if start:
  p1 = p2 = n/2

 median1 = select(DB1,p1)
 median2 = select(DB2,p2)

 if median1 > median2:
  result = median_of_datasets(p1*1/2, p2*3/2, false)
 else:
  result = median_of_datasets(p1*3/2, p2*1/2, false)

 return result
```

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: Please spell out the result of `select(multitude, value)` - and the required result of `median_of_datasets(p1, p2, start)`!